# Componente select2 com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, jquery-select2

Boa tarde

Alguém utiliza o componente select2 (https://github.com/select2/select2) para criar componentes dropdown?

Estou passando pelo seguinte problema, tenho dois componentes em um javascript que são colocados na tela conforme o usuário adiciona novas linhas. E nestes componentes do tipo select2, são colocados a tag ng-model do AngularJS apontando para um atributo de um item por exemplo, porém quando é chamado via AJAX o item com seus atributos o AngularJS não percebe que o valor deveria ser alterado e a classe do componente continua como ng-pristine invés de ng-dirty, utilizando o Google Chrome o input onde fica armazenado o código do item não fica rosa no momento da alteração, o que indica que o valor continuou o mesmo que o recebido quando o usuário informou para criar uma nova linha de itens.

Html no JavaScript que monta o componente na tela:

```
<input  ng-model='item.oid' data-url='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cadastros/item' new-item='true' data-id='oid' data-text='descricao' name='itens[{{$index}}].item.oid' id='item{{$index}}' type='select2' style=' min-width: 300px;' class='form-control' />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar o componente Select2 no AngularJS em recomendo utilizar esse [aqui](http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select).

Para ter o comportamento que você está procurando será necessário criar uma propriedade no Controller (ou qualquer outra coisa) que você estiver utilizando e manipular esta propriedade. Sempre que houver alteração na propriedade com o array de objetos a serem exibidos no componente a atualização ocorrerá em tela.

Comment: E não teria como utilizar da forma como está? O componente está funcionando perfeitamente, é apenas este detalhe que mencionei acima.

Comment: @GiancarloGiulian explique um pouco melhor o que você deseja fazer para tentar lhe ajudar? Ficou um pouco confuso seu texto acima. O componente exibe uma lista que você seleciona para adicionar em algum lugar ou você atualiza a lista e deseja que o componente se atualize?

Comment: o componente exibe uma lista que seleciono para adicionar um dos itens no input, mas queria saber se tem uma maneira de fazer isso sem utilizar o ui-select que você me passou para não precisar adicionar mais um arquivo .js no projeto.

Comment: @GiancarloGiulian pelo que me recordo quando você utiliza este componente ele cria outros elementos em tela, que não estão sobre o escopo do angular, ou seja, o angular não sabe que eles existem. O que você poderia fazer (um pouco de gambiarra) é acionar o método *onchange* deste elemento modificando o valor de algum outro elemento que esse sim esteja sendo observado pelo angular. Para então seu controller fazer alguma coisa através do *watch* do ngModel. Entendeu? (meio complicado explicar isso)

Comment: Muito obrigado @ThiagoDorneles, sua resposta ficou clara, consegui entender.